# What does "IP Address" field in "Site Binding" setting of IIS？

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

What does this setting mean? The IP address that IIS would listen to? Or the IP of ceratin network interface on the server so IIS would only listen to the traffic from that interface?

I had tried to set it to the IP of my server from "All Unassigned" but then my website stopped working immediately... I got the "Connection was reset" error... Then I changed it back to "All Unassigned" and my website resumed working... Why would this happen?

[image: IIS site binding]
[image: ipconfig]
[image: after changed site binding to local IP, connection was reset]

Comment: you can bind it to a specific ip as it states

Comment: @djdomi that is my question, what IP? the IP of an network interface on my machine? then why did my website stop working after I bound it?

Comment: Because, according to your screenshot, you bound it solely to 192.168.0.219 and your browser shows it’s trying to access 127.0.0.1 (or ::1 if it tried over IPv6).

Comment: If you never know how to properly interpret IIS site bindings, you can run a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html